# Use variables in Autosys in std_out_file

Tags: windows, variables, logging, autosys

I'd like to set-up dynamic joblog name each time when job run. I'm fine to add timestamp to joblog. Tried to use below:

```
update_job: ololo_job
std_out_file: >> "%JOBLOG%\ololo_job-%DATE:~0,2%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~8,2%-%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%.log"
```

That doesn't make a trick. Autosys accept the syntax, but then adds "/" before each ":", so Jil starts looking like:

```
std_out_file: >> "%JOBLOG%\ololo_job-%DATE/:~0,2%%DATE/:~3,2%%DATE/:~8,2%-%TIME/:~0,2%%TIME/:~3,2%%TIME/:~6,2%.log"
```

and job fails with "Error redirecting output".
I've tried using just:

```
update_job: ololo_job
std_out_file: >> ololo_job-%DATE%.log
```

Also no luck, log file had the same name rather then date. Had anyone deal with that?

Comment: I have found similar solution for UNIX: std_out_file: path/$AUTO_JOB_NAME.`date "+%m%d"`.out and that works, but how to achieve the same in Windows I don't get.

Comment: Also tried to use Bat file that outputs datetime %JOBLOG%\ololo-job`d\:\\\\Scripts\\\\Bats\\\\getdatetime.bat`.log - the same error dedirecting otput

Answer (score 1):

So:

We can do it in Unix/Linux systems
We can't do it Windows: we can have date, but we can't have time, so for the jobs that run more than 1 time per day, we can "do it like they do it on discovery channel"

%JOBLOG%/%AUTO_JOB_NAME%.%AUTORUNID%.log

Answer (score 1):

`%AUTO_JOB_NAME%.%AUTORUN%` will have a unique id generated